# Get neighboring cell operator names on Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, cellinfo

I am working a little with the [TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getAllCellInfo()). I do receive a list of the neighboring cells in the form of `List<CellInfo>`. However, I can only get the name of the currently connected network (operator name) and not the neighboring networks.

Here is my question: **How do I get the operator name of the neighboring cell networks?** You know, just like the names on the list in: Settings -> Wireless and Networks (More) -> Mobile Networks -> Network operators...

I hope you can help :)

Comment: Did you find the answer for this?

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper Well, I have been searching a lot but still hasn't found a solution that solves the problem. So my project is on pause until I find a solution.

Comment: thanks..I'll also let you know if I find anything..

Comment: Any solution? 5 years passed

Comment: Maybe - I haven't been working on that project for almost 5 years as well, but a lot has changed on Android since then.